# ¿Hay alguna forma de escapar los backticks en los comentarios a las preguntas?

Tags: soporte, formato

Si quiero pegar esta instrucción en un comentario voy a tener problemas con los backticks:

```
 CREATE TABLE `orders` ( `idOrder` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `partialShipment` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `partialShipMin` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `partialShipQty` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', KEY
 `partialShipment` (`partialShipment`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT
 CHARSET=utf8
```

En un comentario, se va a ver así:

`CREATE TABLE` orders`(`idOrder`int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,`partialShipment`tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',`partialShipMin`smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',`partialShipQty`tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', KEY`partialShipment `(`partialShipment`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`

O así:

CREATE TABLE `orders` ( `idOrder` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, `partialShipment` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1', `partialShipMin` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `partialShipQty` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', KEY `partialShipment` (`partialShipment`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

¿Hay alguna forma de escapar los backticks para que todo el `CREATE TABLE` se vea como `código` en el comentario o esto es imposible?

Comment: yo tengo mis serias dudas de que eso debiera estar en un comentario.. el comentario es eso, un comentario.. escribir un create en un comentario, o es una respuesta, o es algo que deberia estar en la pregunta....

Comment: en las base de datos son obligatorios los backstick? la verdad que hasta el día de hoy los evito en los post y comentario...

Comment: ha y no estoy de acuerdo en que se usen los comentarios para colocar codigo de mas de 20 caracteres ... en tal caso crearía una sala de chat ... de los comentarios etc ...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 son obligatorios en aquellos casos en que el elemento pueda confundirse con una palabra reservada o si llevara espaciones en blanco y cosas por estilo, aunque no es una práctica recomendada usar palabras reservadas en las nominaciones.

Comment: @A.Cedano entonces hay una serie de debilidades en el lenguaje que queremos solucionar en los comentarios... con esto toma mas fuerza en mi concepto que se debe evitar poner código en los comentarios, más en un lenguaje que pueda presentar estas características...

Comment: Es irónico que en un sitio de programación haya tales dificultades para tipear código. También que el editor de comentarios sea distinto al de preguntas/respuestas.

Comment: @CandidMoe en casa de Herrero cuchillo de palo ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Para que todo se vea como código, hay que poner doble backticks

Esto:

```
``Algo `entre` comillas.``
```

Se ve así:

`` Algo `entre` comillas. ``

---

En el caso de que texto tenga simples y dobles backticks hay que poner trés.

Esto:

``````
```El ``texto `entre` comillas.`````
``````

Se ve así:

``` El ``texto `entre` comillas``. ```

Y así sucesivamente.

---

Para que nada se vea como código hay que anteponer una barra inclinada hacia atrás (*backslash*).

Esto:

```
Algo \`entre\` comillas.
```

Aparece así:

Algo `entre` comillas.